# dbplyr issues with bigquery in r studio

Tags: sql, r, google-bigquery, dbplyr

So I am taking an online course on data science and they want me to use r studio for bigquery manipulation.

I finally got the code to accept and authenticate my workspace, (by using dbplyr v2.1.1) however I continue to get an error when I go to write a sql-like query.

My code with dummy variables

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(bigrquery)
devtools::install_version('dbplyr', version = '2.1.1')

con <-DBI::dbConnect(drv = bigquery(), project ="project1")
table1 <-tbl(con, "dataset1.table1")
table2 <-tbl(con, "dataset1.table2")

table2 %>% 
  select(variable1)
```

the error I get when running the query is:

Error in UseMethod("op_can_download") :
no applicable method for 'op_can_download' applied to an object of class "NULL"

EDIT: Even when updating to dbplyr 2.4.0 it still returns the same error

EDIT: I installed dbplyr v2.3.4 and was able to get the code running. I found the trick on https://stackoverflow.com/a/77465186/23177253. It seems like the maintainers of dbplyr aren't keeping features updated in their x.x.0 releases.

Comment: Mostly curious, is there a reason to prefer a 2.5-year-old release (2.1.1) instead of the recent 2.4.0? Most "bug reports" or such will ask (/require) that you be on the most recent version.

Comment: i didn't know that dbplyr is already lat 2.4.0 and if it can handle bigquery() then I am could be all about that. I wonder if that is the issue... The course instructors have had people use 2.1.1 because 2.2.0 couldn't handle the biquery functions, so I was under the impression that is where the release version was. Let me try to modify the code and I'll see if that changes anything.

Comment: I apologize, since I don't use `bigrquery` it is mostly speculation. However, looking at the [list of issues containing `bigrquery`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues?q=is%3Aissue+bigrquery+is%3Aclosed), they are all _closed_, meaning either (a) bugs exist but have not been reported, or (b) all bugs have been closed, possibly resolved. Again, I apologize that I cannot confirm that it works on my end, but if true then that is a goo-enough reason to stick with 2.1.1 for now (perhaps the instructors haven't tried recently?).

Comment: `s/goo-enough/good-enough/` :-/

Comment: I ***STRONGLY*** suggest that you submit a [new bug report](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=issue_template.md). The comment *"maintainers ... aren't keeping features updated"* can also be interpreted as they have not been given an issue about this or a clearly reproducible bug report. Give them a chance (and then give them some time), most of those devs are responsive but also juggling _many dozens_ of packages; I find it almost certain that they will not fix a bug they don't know about.

Comment: Yes, it must be a nightmare maintaining `dbplyr` given all the backends and the inherent need to rely on maintainers of other packages (`bigrquery`) to keep things humming. Bug reports might be the only way the package maintainers can even learn about many problems.

Comment: @godislobster, I really think it should be **you** to submit a bug report against `dbplyr`. In one sense, it's unfair for you to say *"aren't keeping features updated"* when you're keeping a secret from them. In another sense, you discovered it, you have a clear reproducible example (I am a user of `bigrquery`). Bugs aren't fixed via osmosis, mind-reading, or random flashes of insight, they are fixed when users responsibly report them. Even if imperfect, just a strong _hint_ of a bug may be enough for the stronger devs.

Comment: @r2evans I will get this reported to them by Friday. Thanks for the suggestion